# Sending Emails on GAE through smtp.gmail.com in Python

Tags: python-2.7, email, google-app-engine, smtp

After reading Google's documentation it should be possible to send an email via smtp.gmail.com on port 465 or 587 on GAE standard.
Reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions_if_lang_is_java_java_7_runtime_only_endif

What is not documented is how to use the socket library.

I am able to send an email via smtplib running the python script locally.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.ehlo()
server.login(gmail_access["email"], gmail_access["password"])
server.sendmail(gmail_access["email"], report.owner, msg.as_string())
server.close()
```

When trying to run the code with GAE's dev_appserver I get the nondescript error "**[Errno 13] Permission denied**"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reasons you are not using the [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/)? Here is a documentation for [sending an e-mail from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api).

Comment: I do not want to be limited to 100 emails a day. If I send through gmail I get 2000 emails. FYI, emailing is for internal use only and authorizing a service account to insert email via Gmail API is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough the error only occurs when trying to run the code locally with dev_appserver.py. After deploying the code to App Engine it worked.

```
import socket
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
msg["Subject"] = subject
msg["From"] = gmail_access["email"]
msg["To"] = report.owner
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "html"))

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(gmail_access["email"], gmail_access["password"])
server.sendmail(gmail_access["email"], report.owner, msg.as_string())
server.close()
```